# Basic Helm Dependency Clarification

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

To ease local development/testing, I have an umbrella chart that deploys all my sub-charts. Those applications make use of resources (e.g. MongoDB, Kafka, etc) and I want to make sure that if you are installing the umbrella chart to a cluster, it will also install those resources.

To do this, I have the following:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: my-cool-project
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  - name: my-cool-app-1
    repository: "file://my-cool-app-1"
  - name: my-cool-app-2
    repository: "file://my-cool-app-2"
  - name: bitnami/kafka
    version: 2.5.0
    repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

Unfortunately, installing this chart throws the following error:

```
Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: bitnami/kafka
```

This seems so fundamental to the concept of Helm that the fact it's not working means I'm clearly missing something basic. Even the [official docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/#synopsis) are pretty clear this is the right approach.

Most documentation/guides instruct you to simply `helm install` it straight to the cluster. While this might solve my immediate problem of needing Kafka or MongoDB on the cluster, my desire is to code-ify the need for that resource so that I can achieve "single chart installs everything to an empty cluster and it just works" status.

What am I missing?

Comment: Run helm dependency update and retry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me :

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: my-cool-project
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  - name: my-cool-app-1
    repository: "file://my-cool-app-1"
  - name: my-cool-app-2
    repository: "file://my-cool-app-2"
  - name: kafka 
    version: 11.6.0 
    repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

Then update on the dependencies on your local helm Chart:

```sh
○ → helm dependency update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading kafka from repo https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
Deleting outdated charts
```

✌️☮️

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I have a much better understanding of the chart/app versions and where they are used now with that example